# Restriction of a Lie bracket on the space of section of a vector bundle..

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles

Let $A\longrightarrow M$ be a vector bundle and $U\subseteq M$ an open set. Suppose I have a lie bracket on $\Gamma(A)$ such that if $\rho:A\longrightarrow TM$ is a bundle map then $$[a, fb]=f[a, b]+\rho(a)(f)b,$$ for all $a, b\in \Gamma(A)$ and $f\in C^\infty(M)$.  I want to show this lie bracket restricts to a Lie bracket $[, ]_U$ on $$\Gamma(U):=\{\gamma|_U: \gamma\in \Gamma(A)\}.$$ I read that it suffices showing that if $a, b\in \Gamma(A)$ vanishes on $U$ then $[a, b]$ also vanish on $U$. I have already shown this but I don't understand why it is sufficient. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: $\Gamma(A)$ is ?

Comment: @SergioParreiras $\Gamma(A)$ is the space of sections.

Comment: Varifying that $[,]_{U}$ is a Lie bracket should be trivial. The only possible problem could be if the bracket is not well defined. Think about what would happen if $[a,b]$ does not vanish on $U$ when $a$ and $b$ do

Comment: Dear PtF, You need some hypotheses on the Lie bracket on $\Gamma(A)$.  Is it linear for the whole ring of smooth functions acting on $\Gamma(A)$, or just for the constant functions?  Regards,

Comment: Indeed there are more hypothesis: if $\rho:A\longrightarrow TM$ is a bundle map then $[a, fb]=f[a, b]+\rho(a)(f)b$ for all $a, b\in \Gamma(A)$ and $f\in C^\infty(M)$. I thought this wouldn't be important, sorry.. As you may see $[, ]$ is not $C^\infty(M)$ linear..